# USB 3.0 hub that will allow connecting two 4TB bus-powered external hard drives

Tags: usb, hard-disk, hub

Please recommend a USB 3.0 hub that can ***definitely*** power 2 external USB 3.0 bus-powered 4TB hard drives at the same time.

Many USB 3.0 hubs claim to be able to do this, but each one I've tried  (and I've tried *many* of them) cause the first external bus-powered hard drive to either:

1. Momentarily disconnect when the second external bus-powered hard drive is plugged in.

or

2. Connect at USB 2.0 speeds when the second drive is plugged in.

Unlike a similar question I asked about a year ago, the hub does not need to have individual switches for each port (but it's fine if it does).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a powered USB hub. They come with a detachable power cable to provide extra electricity when needed, great for driving power-hungry devices such as portable Hard Drives. Here are a few examples from Amazon:

- [TP-Link 9 Port USB 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SCX6I8A)
- [BYEASY 4 Port USB 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M91R8PN)
- [Sabrent 4 Port USB 3.0 with Individual Switches](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TPMEOYM)

Answer (score 0):

I use this [Anker 10 Port 60W Data Hub](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/anker-10-port-60w-data-hub/A7515111) that would have no issues doing what you want, but due to the 3 power only ports at the bottom, it needs to be plugged in with a wall adapter. I have a mouse, Dolby 7.1 Headset, and multiple 24/7 active USB flash drives, and a 3.1 Western Digital 5400rpm drive attached, and I have no issues running these.  To my knowledge Anker doesn't provide a hub that will allow a stable connection from the power on a USB 3.0 port alone.